# adding dynamically labels in uiview and then uiview to scrollview ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to make an app in which I am adding a scrollview in the interface builder and then in .m file I am adding two labels dynamically in an UIView and then this UIView is added dynamically in the scrollview this is done in a for loop.

the code i am using for scrollview:

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + kbSize.height);
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

the code for adding two labels are:

```
UILabel  * label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0 + Y,label1.frame.size.width, 21)];
label1.text = @"label1";
#and all label1 propertiies

UILabel  * label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 21 + Y, label2.frame.size.width, 21)];
label2.text = @"label2";

UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view1.frame.size.width, 42)];

CGRect frame;
frame = view1.frame;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSize){ self.scrollView.contentSize.width,frame.size.height + kbSize.height}];
[self.scrollView addSubview:view1];
                [view1 addSubview:label1];
                [view1 addSubview:label2];
```

the labels are generated but the problem is that i am not able to scroll them down.

I dont know what is the problem. i am new to this.

Is this the right way or is there any other way.

hope the question is clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: probably your contentSize is smaller than the scrollViews frame, or they are equal. You have to make the contentSize bigger.
Also it's not recomanded to set the ContentSize, better use contentInset, here you can find more about contentInset
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset

Comment: can u pls edit the above code?

Comment: @GeorgeK Have you check the resulting value of `frame.size.height + kbSize.height`

Comment: explain exactly what you want, i will try to reproduce, or i will try to give you some advice

Comment: @BogdanSomlea i have a for loop in which a uiview is generated and inside a uiview two labels are generated and this uiview is inside a scrollview.so if for loop runs 10 times there should be 10 uiview inside scrollview and each uiview must have 2 labels.

Comment: and the UIView-s size is equal to the screen size?

Comment: NO...it is not..it is the size of the 2 labels combined

Comment: you are doing a lot of wrong things, i will give you a code, but it's statical, you have to modify it

Comment: instead of what are you doing, i would make a custom UIVIew class, with setters for the 2 labels, and just add as subView to the scrollView instances of that class. But you will still have to set the contentSize or ad the Insets to the scrollView, but still would be a lot more easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code, it will work but i'm not sure if this is what you are searching for

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
CGFloat height;
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 30)];
tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.scrollView addSubview:tf];
for(NSInteger i=1; i<10;i++) {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureMethod:)];
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (i*100), 320, 100)];
    v.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 20)];
    label1.text = @"Label1";

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 20)];
    label2.text = @"Label2";
    [v addSubview:label1];
    [v addSubview:label2];

    v.tag = i;
    [v addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:v];
    height+=100;
}
height+=100;
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, height);
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

/// the gesture selector method down HERE

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)gestureMethod:(id)sender {
UIView *view = [(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender view];
//treat the gesture inside the view based on the tag.
NSLog(@"The tap is in the view with the tag: %ld",(long)view.tag);
}

 -(UIColor *)randomColor
{
NSInteger aRedValue = arc4random()%255;
NSInteger aGreenValue = arc4random()%255;
NSInteger aBlueValue = arc4random()%255;

UIColor *randColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:aRedValue/255.0f green:aGreenValue/255.0f blue:aBlueValue/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
return randColor;
}

 - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

//scroll scrollView to bottom
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size.height, 0);
 }

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
 self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);


}
```

this is the whole code. for me it works, but in the storyboard, you have to add constraints to the scrollView. Leading,Top,Trailing,Bottom contraints from scrollView to the superview, all equal to 0. and you use the notifications for the keyboard appearance. Try it and tell me if you still have problems.

Comment: the code is working fine but when the keyboard is shown some of the text is below the keyboard. how to solve that problem?

Comment: Not able to resolve it...and also i had a doubt, i wanted to add tap functionality to each view, with the above code will i be able to do so?

Comment: yes, you will be able, where is placed your textfield?

Comment: the code is working perfectly for tap, but i am encountering positioning problem for the label(the uiview generated is not working properly, try touching all labels), when i searched i found that i should turn off auto-layout so tried with it but not working, i know i am asking for big favour, pls do help

Comment: ok, i will try, but i don't know what do you have in your storyboard, what constraints, or if you are working with constraints

Comment: did u try it?did u encountered the problem?

Comment: look at my edit, and please tell me if it works, I also added a method for random colors, so i can see if the views are drawn corectly, you can delete it, but I think it will help you

Comment: Good news hearing that, Good luck

Comment: i had one question, i wanted to pass string of format- W44r5cd5t, using the tag but i am not able to pass using above code. i searched for a solution but did not get it. can u help?